# discussions in chat -- when to create a new chat room

Tags: discussion, support, chat

This morning I was getting into a discussion in the comments about the question [Blackstones in DE — what can be inferred from this?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5341/blackstones-in-de-what-can-be-inferred-from-this) so I suggested to @DaveBlackston that we take it to chat.

He created a new room, but I ended up in the general Roots area, so we ended up having a conversation there. Only about halfway through, I figured out that I could have created a room for the topic instead.

Should our discussion in roots be moved to transcript of the associated room he created, so that people can find it more readily?  Or can it be moved?  Next time, should we create a specific room for it? What is the best practice?

When I suggested a chat, I did it to discuss general methodology rather than to address that specific question, so there is an argument for simply leaving things as they are.  But for the future, it would be useful to know what to do about these things.  Dave and I are both chatty so I expect this scenario to come up again, and I don't want to constantly litter the Q/A comments with our back-and-forth volleys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If too much discussion is happening in comments, the system gently nudges you in the direction of creating a specific chat room. Those specific chat rooms are transient and will fade away in time once they go inactive.

I can't see any reason why you shouldn't use [Roots](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6003/roots) -- in fact I'd prefer it as more people may become aware of the discussion and join in.

Comment: As I understand it then, the intent of the designers is for the material in the specific chat rooms to be mined and incorporated into the question at hand?  Thus they go away once the discussion is over?

Comment: @JanMurphy, that sounds about right. Not that I've found anywhere that documents the designers intent.